# wait.until doesn't seem to be waiting correctly

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a test that deletes a specific entry from a table. The page must load, then navigate to the additionalGroupRecharges tab once it is clickable. However, intermittently the driver tries to click on the additionalGroupRecharges tab before it is visible and a "{"Element  could not be scrolled into view"}" exception is thrown.

I have declared a wait-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
//WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));); (Same Issue)
```

Once the user has been logged in, the driver should wait until the additionalGroupRecharges tab becomes clickable and then click on it, like so-

```
string additionalGroupRecharges = "//*[@id='mvcPageControlFinanceData_T2']";
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(additionalGroupRecharges))).Click();
```

I know that the XPath for the tab is correct because this works sometimes, but intermittently it tries to click the button before it is visible.

Full code for this specific test (It is then called in TestMethod)-

```
public static string deleteRecharge(string newReportingName)
    {
        //Opens Firefox and maximizes the browser.
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        //Allows webdriver to execute JavaScript and wait for conditions.
        var javascriptExecutor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        //Buttons
        string deleteButton = "//a[child::img[@title='Delete'] and parent::td[following-sibling::td[text()='" + newReportingName + "']]]";
        string additionalGroupRecharges = "//*[@id='mvcPageControlFinanceData_T2']";

        //Fields
        string firstRow = "//*[@id='additionalGroupRechargeGrid_DXDataRow0']";

        //Filters
        string productNameFilter = "//*[@id='additionalGroupRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol4_I']";

        try
        {
            //Go to the URL and log in, switch to group recharges tab.
            SeleniumHelper.LogIn(driver, "FinanceData/");
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(additionalGroupRecharges))).Click();

            //Search using filters
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(productNameFilter)));
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(productNameFilter)).SendKeys(newReportingName + Keys.Enter);

            string rowData = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(firstRow)).Text;

            //Delete the record containing the newReportingName and assert it is no longer visible.
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(deleteButton)).Click();

            //Click the delete button of the new recharge and assert it is no longer visible.
            Assert.IsFalse(driver.PageSource.Contains(rowData));

            return newReportingName;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Add 1 to number of fails and store the exception.
            TestSetup.Errors.Add(ex.ToString());
            SeleniumHelper.FailCount = SeleniumHelper.FailCount + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return null;
        }

        finally
        {
            //Go to log out URL.
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(SeleniumHelper.BaseUrl + "/Account/Logout.aspx");

            //Close driver.
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
```

Page that is being tested -
[image: additionalGroupRecharges]

Comment: `before it is visible` My guess is it became visible too late (after the wait expired).

Comment: A dumb suggestion: compare two screenshots taken when all is OK and when you get an exception. Split one wait-click action into two phases:  assign the result of wait.intil to a variable, take screenshot, then click. Will there be any difference?

Comment: Probably, there's some activity which, for example, temporary places an overlay over you button. Sometimes you catch that short moment. In that case another straightforward suggestion: sleep for some 0.5 secs between wait.until and clicking.

Comment: What Selenium version you are using?

Comment: Did you try this with ChromeDriver instead of FireFox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by adding this function-

```
    public static void actionwait(Func<bool> action)
    {
        int seconds = 60;

        for (int i = 0; i < seconds * 5; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (action())
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
```

And then calling it like so-

```
            var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(additionalGroupRecharges)));
            SeleniumHelper.actionwait(() => { element.Click(); return true; });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
{"Element could not be scrolled into view"}
```

As your script is unable to *scroll* the element into view, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) for the *WebElement* to be [visible](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm), then *scrollIntoView* and then again induce *WebDriverWait* for the *WebElement* to be [clickabe](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) as follows :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
IWebElement additionalGroupRecharges = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='mvcPageControlFinanceData_T2']")));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",additionalGroupRecharges);
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='mvcPageControlFinanceData_T2']"))).Click();
```

Comment: As I understand from the Selenium API, waiting for ElementToBeClickable means waiting till the Element is Visible and Enabled and Webdriver it selfs scrolls an Element in to view. So what is going wrong in this special case that you are forced to do this al yourself in three different steps instead of just Waiting the for the element to be clickable.

Comment: @Frank You are right. ChromeDriver v2.36 is behaving a bit different. So it is a sort of experiment.